# How to track all the exceptions on parallel tasks in dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, parallel-processing

I have a transaction that includes 12 queries for getting an export from the database and in this situation, I decided to do this with Task.WhenAll() and based on this decision and the ExceptionHandlerMiddleware that I wrote can only catch the first exception, not all of them. what solutions can I have in this case? thanks.

I found these two solutions but I'm worried about concurrency issues and I don't know how to fix this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library

https://thesharperdev.com/csharps-whenall-and-exception-handling/

Comment: Why you only get the first? You should get an AggregateException and how to handle the set of attached Exceptions is described in your first link.

Comment: What do you mean "track" exactly? You can always put a `catch` block inside the thread, and it can call your exception handler directly. If you're worried your exception handler is not thread-safe, please post your code.

Comment: Hi Ali. Could you edit the question and show how you use the `Task.WhenAll` method, including the try/catch block?

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle this is not allow exceptions within the task in the first place.  You can accomplish this by having each task catch any unhandled exceptions and then store the text in an Error property.  After tasks have completed you can inspect their Error property in the main thread and any with `Error.Length != 0` can be printed out.

Here is an example of [Gigantor's FileMapJoin class](https://github.com/imagibee/Gigantor/blob/main/Gigantor/FileMapJoin.cs#L236) behaving as described above.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Why store only the text, and not the Exception object as is?